# Why does this return a different value outside the function

Tags: python, variables

When I print the variable inside the function, it prints exactly what I want. However when I print it outside the function, it prints the file location instead of the actual value in the file.

```
def go():
    username = os.getlogin()
    file2 = ('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryourmessagehere.txt')
    if os.path.exists(file2):
        try:
            os.rename(file2,file2+"_")
            file = open('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryormessagehere.txt', 'r').read()
            os.remove('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryormessagehere.txt')
            main4()
            return file
        except OSError as e:

            file2 = open('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryourmessagehere.txt_', 'r').read()
            os.remove('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryourmessagehere.txt_')
            print (file2)
            main4()


    return file2

def main4():
    file2 = go()
    print (file2)
```

The output of inside the function go is whatever is in the file, however the output of of the function main4 is C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryormessagehere.txt

Comment: `go` is not a variable, it's a function just like `main4`. Your terminology is confusing. As is your indentation.

Comment: Fixed the indentations, I said variable by mistake changed that too. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
def go():
    username = os.getlogin()
    file2 = ('C:/Users/'+username+'/enteryourmessagehere.txt')
    # …
    return file2

def main4():
    file2 = go()
    print (file2)
```

This is the relevant part of your code. `file2` is the file name, so when you return `file2`, you are returning the file name and as such print that one.

`file2` does get changed, but only when there is an `OSError`. It’s a really good idea to use variable names that tell you what something is. E.g. use `fileName` or `filePath` for file names or paths, and for the file content use something that makes it clear that it’s some content, e.g. `fileContent`, or `userMessage` (if that makes sense in your context).

Finally, I’m not sure what you’re actually doing there. You are recursively calling `go` and `main` in alternation, that seems a bit weird and unstable. You should think about changing that.

Comment: With this code I am trying to print the contents of the file 'enteryourmessagehere' after it has been closed because in another function above, the user has the chance to edit the contents.  After they finish and save the file, I want to output the contents. Hopefully that makes sense.